# python encoding error with utf-8

Tags: python, file

I want write some strings to file which is not in English, they are in Azeri language. Even if I do utf-8 encoding I get following error:

```
    TypeError: write() argument must be str, not bytes
```

Even if I make code as:

```
        t_w = text_list[y].encode('utf-8')
        new_file.write(t_w)
        new_file.write('\n')
```

I get following error which is :

```
TypeError: write() argument must be str, not bytes
```

The reason why I dont open file as 'wb' is I am writing different strings and integers to file.

Comment: If you’re calling `encode` on `text_list[y]`, `text_list[y]` must be a `str`. So `t_w = text_list[y]` should work.

Comment: what is in `text_list[y]`? Right now you are encoding it to be bytes.. perhaps you forgot to`decode` it after encoding it to utf8?

Comment: @IsmailKerimov: You mean a literal backslash character? Sounds like there was a mistaken `repr` somewhere before this.

Comment: type of text_list[y] is str,
when I dont do encoding I get following error: UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 10-12: ordinal not in range(128)

Comment: @Ryan for instance instead of ü it writes /xc3

Comment: Try opening `new_file` with `encoding='utf-8'`. (`with open('…', 'w', encoding='utf-8') as new_file:`)

Comment: @Ryan thank you very much you saved my day!

Answer (score 0):

If `text_list` contains unicode strings you should encode (not decode) them to string before saving to file.

Try this instead:

```
    t_w = text_list[y].encode('utf-8')
```

Also it could be helpful to look at codecs standard module https://docs.python.org/2/library/codecs.html. You could try this:

```
    import codecs
    with codecs.open('path/to/file', 'w', 'utf-8') as f:
        f.write(text_list[y])
        f.write(u'\n')
```

But note that codecs always opens files in binary mode.

Answer (score 0):

When using write in text mode, the UTF-8 mode is the default (in Python 3, I assume you use only Python 3, not Python 2) so do not encode the strings. Or open your file in binary mode and encode EVERYTHING you write to your file. I suggest NOT using binary mode in your case. So, your code will look like this:

```
with open('myfile.txt', 'w') as new_file:
    t_w = text_list[y]
    new_file.write(t_w)
    new_file.write('\n')
```

or for Python 2:

```
new_file = open('myfile.txt', 'wb')
t_w = text_list[y].encode('utf-8') # I assume you use Unicode strings
new_file.write(t_w)
new_file.write(ub'\n')
new_file.close()
```